# cant install pip in ubuntu 18.04 docker /bin/sh: 1: pip: not found

Tags: python, docker, pip, dockerfile, ubuntu-18.04

I am getting the error using pip in my docker image.

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository universe
RUN apt-get install -y \
    python3.6 \
    python3-pip

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /api
WORKDIR /api

COPY . /api/
RUN pip install pipenv
RUN ls
RUN pipenv sync
```

I installed python 3.6 and pip3 but getting

```
Step 9/11 : RUN pip install pipenv
 ---> Running in b184de4eb28e
/bin/sh: 1: pip: not found
```

Comment: Just an idea: have you considered using `python:3.6` instead of `ubuntu:18.04`? It comes with `pip` already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To run `pip` for python3 use `pip3`, not `pip`.

Comment: this did not solve my problem inside a ubuntu docker container

Answer (score 2):

Another solution.

You can add this line (after apt-get install). It will upgrade pip to the version you need, for instance:

```
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip==20.0.1
```

and you can then use `pip install` from requirements file (for instance):

```
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```