# Ubuntu Command 'pip' not found, but there are 18 similar ones (pandas) reintalling works uslly

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I tried reinstalling it ,but for us to install pythin packages use the pip's version to specify instaltion for ex pip3 install pandas.

Comment: Try using `pip-3`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cant install pip in ubuntu 18.04 docker /bin/sh: 1: pip: not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60435261/cant-install-pip-in-ubuntu-18-04-docker-bin-sh-1-pip-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

Try to install pip with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Or:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```